# Locale is not updating in release bundle

Tags: android, setlocale

Locale is no updating in release bundle,but it is working in debug apk.
I am using
targetSdkVersion 29 and
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02

In MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.updateResources(base));
}


public class LocaleManager {

public static String TAG = "LocaleManager";
public static String LOCALE_HI = "hi_IN";
public static String LOCALE_EN = "en_US";
private static String lan_str;
private static String country_str;
public static void setlan(String str)
{
    String val[] = str.split("_");
    LocaleManager.lan_str = val[0];
    LocaleManager.country_str = val[1];
}

public static String getlanguage()
{
    return LocaleManager.lan_str+"_"+LocaleManager.country_str;
}

 public static Context updateResources(Context context) {

    if(lan_str == null || country_str == null)
        return context;

    Locale locale = new Locale(lan_str,country_str);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

}

I am doing re-lunch MainActivity after change language, but locale not update.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for locate
added this inside the android block of app build.gradle

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```

referenced from https://www.mmbyte.com/article/55895.html .
Thanks